# Permutation of natural numbers

Tags: permutations

Find the number of permutation of {1,2,3,4,5,6} such that the patterns 13 and 246 do not appear. Show the steps .

Comment: This is not a "do my homework for me" site. Explain us what  you've tried.

Comment: For the future, this sort of question is not about [tag:permutation-groups]... That's a different topic.  ;)

Comment: Thank you @leonbloy for reminding ! but my intension was not that. I have solved it and wanted to check my solutions is correct or not.

Comment: @U-47 Then you should post your proposed solution as part of your question.  It is easier to verify that a solution is correct than to find a solution from scratch.  (Besides, what if you get an answer with a solution that is different from yours?  That doesn't mean that yours is incorrect.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to first find the number of permutations in which the pattern $13$ or $246$ does appear.

For the pattern $13$, tie $1$ and $3$ together to make a supersymbol. Together with $2,4,5,6$, and the supersymbol. we have $5$ "symbols" that can be arranged in $5!$ ways.

Similarly, there are $4!$ ways in which the pattern $246$ appears.

There are $3!$ ways in which both patterns appear. These are counted twice in the sum $5!+4!$.

Thus there are $5!+4!-3!$ ways thast one or both of our patterns can appear. It follows that there are $6!-(5!+4!-3!)$ ways to arrange our symbols so that neither pattern appears.